# Speeding up the scala.js/sbt Edit-Compile-Run/Debug cycle

Tags: playframework, sbt, scala.js

The Edit-Compile-Run cycle for my Play+Scala.JS application is painfully slow.  I'm wondering if you have tips for speeding it up.

For example, is there a way to avoid restarting the server every time the client (scala.js) code changes?  We don't need to close and re-open database connections and all just to serve a new javascript file!  @aholland makes partial progress on this at https://github.com/aholland/play-scalajs-workbench-example but his technique involves manually splitting the project into the server part and the client part and then (manually) merging them again.  Ugh!

@OlivierBanvillain's sample project at https://github.com/OlivierBlanvillain/full-stack-scala says it has "proper sbt configuration for development/deployment".  The build.sbt file does some interesting things with which files are watched for changes, etc.  But I don't see a difference in actual use:  the play server still restarts every time scala.js source is changed.  Perhaps I misunderstand his intent (the explanation is pretty sparse!).

I've also seen the sbt-revolver plugin (https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver) -- in fact the above project uses it.  It advertises "dangerously fast development turnaround in Scala" but again, I don't understand what its advantage is.  It talks about starting/stopping the application in the background, but how is that different than normal sbt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rewrote my build.sbt file using the example from https://github.com/vmunier/play-with-scalajs-example, including the plugins.  That's helped a lot.